# Is there a way to launch Unity Dash outside of Unity?

Tags: 10.10, launcher, gnome, unity-2d, wingpanel

I've installed Unity 2d, and therefore I'm able to use the Launcher and Panel in standard Gnome Panel desktop. I would like to know whether there is a way to launch the Dash only, and if so, if it is possible to assign a shortcut to it. What I'm thinking of is a Wingpanel + Slingshot combo on Elementary or Gnome-Shell style 'Activities' button. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity 2D's dash can be used independently but there is a little trick: it starts invisible.

To launch it type:

```
unity-2d-places
```

To make it visible, there is a D-Bus API:

```
bool com.canonical.Unity2d.Dash.active
```

From the command line:

```
qdbus com.canonical.Unity2d.Dash /Dash active true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I was convinced my question would go unanswered!