# What is the easiest way to launch Dash with a single-touch screen and auto-hidden launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, 11.10, unity-dash, touchscreen

There is a lot of devices with a single-touch screen and the Oneiric Unity has no always-visible Dash icon. So, how can I get it without keyboard providing that moving pointer to the edge is almost impossible on the majority of resistive touchscreens?

One way I know of is to use `easystroke` with Button1 for gestures and short timeout. Didn't try Win-button emulation yet but there is a CLI way:
[Is there a way to launch Unity Dash outside of Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28429/is-there-a-way-to-launch-unity-dash-outside-of-unity)

Another ways you know of such as easy Taskbar-icon creation?

Comment: Could you try setting the launcher to "always visible"? You'll lose some screen space but I think it would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your launcher to be always-visible:

'CompizConfig Settings Manager' (CCSM) >> Category: Desktop >>
  'Ubuntu Unity Plugin' >> Behavior >> Hide Launcher: Never

I have already set this, as I did not like the disappearing / windowing re-sizing of the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a keyboard, hit the Windows/Super button.

Comment: Thanks, but that is the main point - to find a workaround for tablets :)

Comment: Oh right. I would suggest using bntser's solution until 12.04 comes out.