# KDE - App activator on [Meta] key

Tags: kde, widgets

I'm using KDE now. In Unity, I could open Dash with <kbd>Meta</kbd>. I want to do the same in KDE - open Application Activator with <kbd>Meta</kbd> key, but I don't know, how. In this widget's properties I can't set it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Unity but this is of the Unity 2d: [Is there a way to launch Unity Dash outside of Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28429/is-there-a-way-to-launch-unity-dash-outside-of-unity)

You could add those commands to the KDE Menu and assign a keyboard shortcut.

KDE Menu editor online handbook: http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html

Adding things to the K-Menu: Chapter 2. Adding a Menu Entry.

The advanced tab has the current shortcut key:

> Current shortcut key:
>
> You can assign a special keyboard shortcut to launch your program.